# java while loop not working as expected

Tags: java

I am using `while` loop to run the logic until both the int values are same.below is the code and compiler executes the while condition, it skips.

```
        while(paramCnt == threshold_value){
            ps.setString(paramCnt++, "abc");
        }
```

code is not working when `paramCnt` value is less than threshold_value. I want to run it until both values are equal.

I was not sure of where i am doing wrong. any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to "run it _until_ both are equal", you need `while (paramCnt != threshold_value)`. This runs it _while_ both are equal.

Comment: Remove the **java-ee** tag from your post. The question has nothing to do with **java-ee**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while loop executes the code between it's brackets while a condition is true. Your condition is not true from the start. In order to loop until both values are equal you could change your condition to:

```
while(paramCnt != threshold_value){
    ...
}
```

Now you would be looping until paramCnt and threshold_value are equal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop until they equal, it means keep looping if they don't equal:

```
while(paramCnt != threshold_value){
     ps.setString(paramCnt++, "abc");
}
```